# Tips to Run an In Person JavaScript Algorithm Meetup Study Group

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I live in a suburb of Seattle (Redmond, WA) and would like to organize a meetup of an in person, JavaScript algorithm study group.

What StackExchange community should I post this question in? Should if be StackOverflow.com?

I've asked multiple questions in StackExchange communities and sometimes have gotten these questions rejected or down voted.

Comment: There is no Stack site you can use to organize something like this. Perhaps make a Facebook group?

Comment: Hi Mark Kirby,
No, I'm not trying to run a group through StackExchange or one the StackExchange websites.

I'm just asking for tips to run a successful JavaScript algorithm study group via Meetup.

Comment: @risingPhoenix1979 What is "JavaScript algorithm"?

Comment: In that case, at a push https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ you could frame it as a question about etiquette in that situation but they do have a strict set of topics they allow, so I am not too sure https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You do have the rep to post in SO chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ and they have a room for discussing Java stuff, might be worth a shot if you are just looking for some tips.

Comment: @MarkKirby Java is not JavaScript

Comment: This question is not off-topic. It is asking if there is anywhere on the network that one can make a post soliciting participation in a meetup group. The answer is that there is no such place. The question is answerable and on-topic.

Comment: risingPhoenix1979, try this site: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meetup and make certain you are [on-topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but a YouTube video might be more helpful, such as this one:  https://youtu.be/GIGImffR67E from their Channel  https://www.youtube.com/meetup or this much longer one: https://youtu.be/9BkQ0ndpljw

Answer (score 6):

Practically speaking, because this is a meetup oriented around a technology and not around an Exchange site, there would be no appropriate place to put this because it's neither a question that would be on-topic for a site, nor is it a meta-question since it's not oriented around the Exchange site.

As an FYI:  other Meta sites have held successful meetups **specifically for their community**.  This isn't that situation or circumstance.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a high-rep user on [Interpersonal.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/), which was [thrown out as a suggestion in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344651/tips-to-run-an-in-person-javascript-algorithm-meetup-study-group#comment1154801_344651), so I wanted to chime in.

As it stands, your question sounds off-topic for IPS. But that could also just be because you're keeping it broad enough to put in a single sentence.

For example, if you were looking for help pitching this idea to individual friends, we could absolutely help you. Or if you were trying to figure out how to bring it up in a group conversation and capture your friends' interest, again we can help. But if you're looking for what to post on your facebook group/meetup page, I'm afraid that'd likely be off-topic (for us at least). IPS tends to focus on specific interpersonal interactions.

If you think we might be the place for you and you want to get some more eyes on your question, IPS has its own [Sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3129/11811) where you can post a draft of your question to have it reviewed by users of the site. We can give you tips and make sure it's in good shape before you try to post it on our main.

If you're not quite sure IPS will work for you (you're closer to the facebook group/meetup page type of question), you can always drop into [our chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/61165). There's usually a good amount of hustle and bustle happening in there with at least a handful high-rep users who will be able to answer any questions you have about site policy.